# (JavaScript) Function returning an undefined value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function that reads from a Firebase database and would return any data it finds about a user.

authorize.js:

```
const login = (db, token) => {
    db.collection('users').get().then(async (e) => {
        var i = []
        e.forEach(async (doc) => {
            if (doc.data().access_token === token){
                i.push(doc.data().id)
                return doc.data()
            }
        })
        if (i.length === 0) return false
    }).catch((error) => {
        return false
    })
}
module.exports = login
```

app.js:

```
app.post('/token/:token', async (req, res) => {
    res.send(await login(db, req.params.token))
})
```

In `authorize.js`, I catch the error, but don't log it. When I `console.log()` the value that would've been returned directly inside the function, no errors occur and it gives me my desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing two `return`s. Also, you have the function inside the `e.forEach` `async` which means it will run after the rest of your code so you won't get your result, remove that (since you aren't doing anything async there anyway):

```js
const login = (db, token) => {
    // v HERE v - you need to return the promise
    return db.collection('users').get().then(async (e) => {
        var i = []
        // v HERE v - no async
        e.forEach((doc) => {
            if (doc.data().access_token === token){
                i.push(doc.data().id)
                // Also, no need for a return here, since it doesn't do anything
            }
        })
        if (i.length === 0) return false
        return i // << instead, here was another return missing
    }).catch((error) => {
        return false
    })
}
module.exports = login
```

A clearer way would be to make `login` also `async`, then you could just use `await` there as well:

```js
async function login (db, token) {
    try {
        const e = await db.collection('users').get()
        const i = []

        for (const doc of e) {
            if (doc.data().access_token === token){
                i.push(doc.data().id)
            }
        }

        if (i.length === 0) return false
        return i
    } catch (e) {
        return false
    }
}

module.exports = login
```

This could be further simplified:

```js
async function login (db, token) {
    try {
        const matchingUserIds = await db.collection('users').get()
            .map(doc => doc.data())
            .filter(docData => docData.access_token === token)
            .map(docData => docData.id)

        return matchingUserIds.length ? matchingUserIds : false
    } catch (e) {
        return false
    }
}

module.exports = login
```

(I wonder though if there isn't any better method to filter the users by access token in your database. Right now it seems like you'll fetch *all* users and then check for the token in this function; it would probably be more scalable to query the database by token in the first place.)

Answer (score 0):

An async function always go with an await and am not seeing any await right inside the function.

More clarity.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer!